# Symfony serializer cannot deserialize into \DateTime

Tags: php, json, symfony, datetime, serialization

I‘m trying to deserialize a json with the Symfony Serializer into a DTO, but I got always the exception `Symfony/Component/Serializer/Exception/MissingConstructorArgumentsException with message 'Cannot create an instance of DateTime from serialized data because its constructor requires parameter "time" to be present.'`.

My DTO looks like this:

```php
class ResponseDto
{
    /** @var \DateTime */
    private $creationDate;


    /** @var NestedObject */
    private $result;


    public function __construct(
        \DateTime $creationDate,
        NestedObject $result
    ) { /* … */ }

    public function getCreationDate(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->creationDate;
    }

    public function getResult(): NestedObject
    {
        return $this->result;
    }
}
```

with a json like this:

```
[
  {
    "result":{
      "operations":{
        "successful":319698,
        "failed":2,
        "total":319700
      }
    },
    "creationDate":"2020-02-10T03:01:53.357Z"
  },
  // …
]
```

The deserialize call is also straight forward:

```php
$serializer->deserialize(
    $data,
    ResponseDto::class . '[]',
    'json'
);
```

And all necessary normalizer (and the symfony/property-info package) are installed/registered too:

```sh
$ bin/console debug:container serializer --show-arguments

Information for Service "serializer"
====================================

 Serializer serializes and deserializes data.

 ---------------- ----------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                    
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       serializer                               
  Class            Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer  
  Tags             -                                        
  Public           yes                                      
  Synthetic        no                                       
  Lazy             no                                       
  Shared           yes                                      
  Abstract         no                                       
  Autowired        no                                       
  Autoconfigured   no                                       
  Arguments        Array (9 element(s))                     
                   Array (5 element(s))                     
 ---------------- ----------------------------------------- 


$ bin/console debug:container --tag serializer.normalizer

Symfony Container Services Tagged with "serializer.normalizer" Tag
==================================================================

 ------------------------------------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID                                        priority   Class name                                                                 
 ------------------------------------------------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  fos_rest.serializer.form_error_normalizer         -10        FOS\RestBundle\Serializer\Normalizer\FormErrorNormalizer                   
  reporting.reader.serializer                                  Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer                                    
  serializer.denormalizer.array                     -990       Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer                  
  serializer.normalizer.constraint_violation_list   -915       Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ConstraintViolationListNormalizer  
  serializer.normalizer.data_uri                    -920       Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DataUriNormalizer                  
  serializer.normalizer.dateinterval                -915       Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateIntervalNormalizer             
  serializer.normalizer.datetime                    -910       Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer                 
  serializer.normalizer.json_serializable           -900       Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\JsonSerializableNormalizer         
  serializer.normalizer.object                      -1000      Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer                   
 ------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why is the serializer not able to deserialize the data into a `\DateTime` object? The `DateTimeNormalizer::supportsDenormalization()` is also called and returning `true` for the property, but `DateTimeNormalizer::denormalize()` is never called.

Fun fact: If I change the type hint to `\DateTimeInterface` the serializer can deserialize the data, but produces `\DateTimeImmutable` (unfortunately I need `\DateTime` objects).

Comment: I don't have the setup to test the serialize/deserialize process right now. As far as i have read the documentation, i would also expect your Code to work. In the deserialization process, the `DateTime` object is created in the [`DateTimeNormalizer` in Line 101](https://github.com/symfony/serializer/blob/master/Normalizer/DateTimeNormalizer.php#L101). In your situation I would put a debugger breakpoint on the line where the exception is thrown and try to figure out why `data` is not there by going through all debug layers. You can debug PHP with [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

As shown before, there is a `reporting.reader.serializer` service tagged as `serializer.normalizer`, but only with a small set of normalizers and encoders configured:

```
services:
    reporting.reader.serializer:
        class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer
        arguments:
            - ['@serializer.normalizer.object']
            - ['@serializer.encoder.csv']
```

This serializer has not a priority, so it is called before the `DateTimeNormalizer`. This way all objects are created by this serializer, but this serializer cannot deserialize interfaces like `\DateTimeInterface` (that‘s the reason this type hint worked and I got `\DateTimeImmutable`).

I fixed this by setting `autoconfigure: false` for the `reporting.reader.serializer` service.